# Trigger is not working in my case

Tags: jquery

Hi all i am trying to fire click event of a  on input changing in it.But it is not working. Please someone find mistakes i have done in my code.Below is my HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="a"><div class="x"><label for="a">ClickHere</label></div></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="b"><div class="x"><label for="b">ClickHere</label></div>      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="c"><div class="x"><label for="c">ClickHere</label></div></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="d"><div class="x"><label for="d">ClickHere</label></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Below is my Jquery code..

```
          $('TABLE TBODY TR').delegate(':radio','change',function()
  {
         $(this).parents('td').trigger('click')
         if(($(this).parents('TD').find('input').filter(':checked').length)*1 > 0)
          {
           $(this).parents('TR').children('td').not($(this).parent('TD')).find('input').prop('checked',false)
           $(this).parents('TD').find('input').prop('checked','checked')
          }
  });
  $('TABLE TBODY TR').delegate(':checkbox','change',function()
  {
      $(this).parents('td').trigger('click')
      if($(this).parents('TD').find('input').length > 1)
      {
          if(($(this).parents('TD').find('input').filter(':checked').length)*1 > 0)
          {
           $(this).parents('TD').find(":radio").prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'))
           $(this).parents('TR').children('TD').not($(this).parent('TD')).find('input').prop('checked',false)
           $(this).closest('TR').children('TD').not($(this).parent('TD')).find(':radio').prop('checked',false);  
          }
      }
      if(($(this).parents('TD').find('input').filter(':checked').length)*1 > 0)
          {
       $(this).parents('TR').children('TD').not($(this).parent('TD')).find('input').prop('checked',false)  
          }
  });    
$('TABLE TBODY TR').delegate('TD','click',function()
{
     alert("Clicked index is"+$(this).index())
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand, what exactly you want, but try this:

```
$('TABLE TBODY TR TD').click(function()
{
     alert("Clicked index is"+$(this).index())
});
```